# How do you bind a ComboBox's SelectedItem to an object that is a copy of an item from ItemsSource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I'm using the MVVM pattern with WPF and have run into a problem, which I can simplify to the following:

I have a CardType model.

```
public class CardType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a viewmodel that consumes CardType.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CardType selectedCardType;
    public CardType SelectedCardType
    {
        get { return selectedCardType; }
        set
        {
            selectedCardType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCardType));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<CardType> CardTypes { get; set; } 

    // ... and so on ...
}
```

My XAML has a ComboBox that bases its items on CardTypes and should preselect an item based on SelectedCardType.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CardTypes}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCardType}"/>
```

For reasons outside of my control, the SelectedCardType object will be a **reference-unequal copy** of the item in CardTypes.  Therefore WPF fails to match the SelectedItem to an item in ItemsSource, and when I run the app, the ComboBox initially appears with no item selected.

I tried overriding the Equals() and GetHashCode() methods on CardType, but WPF still fails to match the items.

Given my peculiar constraints, how can I get ComboBox to select the correct item?

Comment: While the top voted answer works, this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24776204/1121033 is a more elegant solution to the same question.

Answer (score 11):

You might not be overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` properly. This should work for you. (However, just overriding Equals will work in your case but it's considered to be good practice to override GetHashCode too when you override Equals for a class)

```
public class CardType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        CardType cardType = obj as CardType;
        return cardType.Id == Id && cardType.Name == Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode() & Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: I quickly tried it out in small sample and worked perfectly fine for me. Can you add code that how are you setting SelectedCardType from code?

Comment: `Id.GetHashCode()` can be replaced with just `Id`

Answer (score 6):

You can use SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CardTypes}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ProductId, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

Where ProductId is a int property with NotifyPropertyChanged.

Read a great explanation here:
[Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath)

Comment: This would require me to change my viewmodel's SelectedCardType property to an integer, which I am not free to do.

Comment: Ok, for sure with this method you have at least to add an integer.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that you could do is to bind your SelectedItem to a string (instead of cardType), then create an object of type CardType using this string?