# Identify object by property instead of reference when binding without overriding Equals

Tags: c#, wpf, vue.js, xaml, vuejs2

I would like my objects bound to ComboBox to be identified by Id instead of a reference. Is there anyway to do this in XAML without overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Minimal example:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
    SelectedValuePath="Id" />
<Button
    Height="32"
    Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
    Content="Test assign" />
```

Code-behind:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person _selectedPerson;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get => _selectedPerson;
        set
        {
            _selectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPerson));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>
    {
        new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Angelina Jolie"},
        new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Brad Pitt"}
    };

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedPerson = new Person {Id = 1, Name = "Angelina Jolie"};
        // SelectedPerson = People[0]; will work but i don't want that 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm assigning `SelectedPerson` to a new object but with the same Name and Id but it doesn't work. ComboBox still compares by reference.

In Vue and other frameworks, it's possible to specify a "key" used to identify objects while binding. `v-bind:key` https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

It works if you override `Equals`: [How do you bind a ComboBox's SelectedItem to an object that is a copy of an item from ItemsSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140431/how-do-you-bind-a-comboboxs-selecteditem-to-an-object-that-is-a-copy-of-an-item) but I wonder if there's any way to avoid that.

I was hoping `SelectedValuePath` will do what I want but I was wrong, it just affects the return value of `SelectedValue`

Comment: Why are you opposed to using the working solution yo already have that solves the problem perfectly?

Comment: @Servy which working solution? Do you mean overriding `Equals`?

Comment: Do you have another working solution that you're unwilling to use besides that?

Comment: @Servy I was hoping there's a simpler solution other than overriding `Equals`

Comment: Why is overriding a method not simple enough?  It's a single line of code that's only a handful of characters long...I guess two lines of code if you provide a `GetHashCode` implementation as well, which you probably should.

Comment: It's simple but doing it in XAML would be simpler.

Comment: Can you tell me why u cant use it `SelectedPerson = People[0];`

Comment: @AvinashReddy because data can be fetched multiple times during application lifetime and addresses will be different.

Comment: @Konrad Why do you think it's simpler to define equality for a type every single time you use it instead of one in that type's definition?

Comment: In Vue and possibly other js frameworks this is possible to specify with an attribute.

Comment: You can replace the new object based on id in `People` Collection

Comment: @Servy it seems cleaner to me, but you're right. I was just wondering if there's a different solution

Comment: @AvinashReddy that sounds over-complicated.

Comment: @Konrad `SelectedPerson = People[0]` is definitly the right thing to do. You are asking for trouble if you have multiple copies of the same object with different states in this viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to do this in XAML without overriding Equals and GetHashCode?

No, there isn't.

You could bind the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox` to a `int` source property, i.e. change the type of `SelectedPerson`, but if you want to bind the `SelectedItem` property to a `Person` property, you'll have to override `Equals`.

Answer (score 1):

When you set

```
SelectedValuePath="Id"
```

the property that `SelectedValue` is bound to should be of the same type as `Id` (in contrast to `SelectedItem`, which should bind to a property of the item type).

E.g.

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPersonId}"
```

with

```
public int SelectedPersonId
{
    get => _selectedPersonId;
    set
    {
        _selectedPersonId = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPersonId));
    }
}
```

You do not need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.